# Building Heatmap with two separate series having "Year" and "Month" information

Tags: pandas, dataframe, seaborn, data-analysis

I am working on a dataset

```py
d = {'date_added_month': ['February', 'December', 'October', 'December', 'April','December', 'March', 'April'], 
     'date_added_year': [2014, 2012, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013],
    'title': ['apple', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'fish', 'goat', 'horse'],
    'titles_count': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image: Name of Titles segregated by Months and Years]

I want to build a heatmap with years on X-axis and Months on Y-axis and count the number of titles on a particular month and year. How do I count the number of titles month and year wise?

I have counted the titles in both Month and Year basis, like this:

```
grp_by_yr = df.groupby("date_added_year").size()
grp_by_mn =  df.groupby("date_added_month").size()
```

But I am not sure how to aggregate both this information.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your data but text that can be copied and used to find an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @werner I realize I shouldn't have posted a non-reproducible code. But I edited the question now, please have a look.

Comment: I think you are looking for `pd.crosstab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fill the `titles_count` with 1 first, since they denote 1 count per row.

```py
release_dist_df['titles_count'] = 1
```

Then pivot the table like so -

```py
heatmap1_data = pd.pivot_table(release_dist_df, values='titles_count', 
                     index=['date_added_month'], 
                     columns='date_added_year')
```

Then plot using seaborn -

```py
sns.heatmap(heatmap1_data, cmap="YlGnBu")
```

### Update

Update with grouping as requested

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'date_added_month': ['February', 'February', 'December', 'October', 'December', 'April','December', 'March', 'April'],
     'date_added_year': [2014, 2014, 2012, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013],
    'title': ['apple', 'apple-new', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'fish', 'goat', 'horse'],
    'titles_count': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['titles_count'] = 1

group_by_both = df.groupby(["date_added_year", "date_added_month"]).agg({'titles_count': 'sum'})

heatmap1_data = pd.pivot_table(group_by_both, values='titles_count',
                     index=['date_added_month'],
                     columns='date_added_year')
print(heatmap1_data)

import seaborn as sns
sns_plot = sns.heatmap(heatmap1_data, cmap="YlGnBu")
```

I also added one more data point to show that aggregation is working (2014 February).
[image: heatmap]

Comment: I actually want to count the number of titles on a particular month and year, not just whether or not the titles are present. I have edited the code to male it reproducible, please have a look.

Comment: You can do so by `group_by_both = df.groupby(["date_added_year", "date_added_month"]).count()`, this will create nested groups.

Comment: Thanks @Yatharth Ranjan, It works after using group_by_both